# Why don't trusted host settings change in my site?

Tags: 9

I decided to change the URL of my Drupal site since it's not secure to include the IP address in it. So in my settings.php I have:

```php
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^forms\.org$',
  '^www\.forms\.org$',
);
```

I cleared the cache using `drush cr` but the trusted host settings in the status report are still not updated. I even checked the permissions and everything is fine.

Comment: You are using probably the wrong settings.php or you have the statement twice in the settings.php file.

Comment: There's an easy way to find out - put some nonsense (i.e. invalid PHP) at the bottom of settings.php and reload the page. If it's not a 500, that settings.php isn't being read. Also check files that you're including via settings.php

Answer (score 1):

*However, the site loads when I use the old URL, which is the ip address one even after I commented it out*

When you have commented the trusted host setting out the site works normally for all domains or IPs, you only get a warning if you open the status page.

*whereas the new address says "files not found"*

This error is not connected to this issue and it's unlikely a Drupal issue at all. Check the VirtualHost of the new address in your web server configuration. You can also test the new domain name with a static HTML file before you start to debug Drupal.

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer. I have "http://forms.org *.forms.org" in ServerAlias of drupal.conf, restarted the httpd and enabled it and still the same. I even tried with https.